# How do I get a fixed pointer to a MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pointers, unsafe

I have a memorystream object to which I need a fixed pointer (I am using VB.net, I think this equates to IntPtr). I need this because a pointer (IntPtr) is required as input parameter to another function (that I cannot modify).

I have not worked with unsafe code before and I understand that this might be required. I could switch to C# if required.

I read here (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pointers-in-C-Sharp/) that "We can say that pointers can point to only unmanaged types which includes all basic data types, enum types, other pointer types and structs which contain only unmanaged types."

This explains why wrapping the memorystream in a struct and using the below code did not work (myTest is a struct that contains the memorystream)

```
Dim gcHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(myTest, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim thePointer As IntPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gchandle))
```

So my question is how can I get a fixed pointer to my memorystream object with VB.net (preferred) or C#? I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: see if https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0 helps you

Comment: Can you work with a byte array instead? You can have `var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);`. You could pass `handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()`, let the method modify the byte array, then get `var array = handle.Target as byte[]; handle.Free();`. Build a MemoryStream from the array, if needed, in the end.

Comment: Alternatively, if you already have the stream, you could use [`ms.GetBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=net-5.0), and pin that as @Jimi says. Don't forget: pinning should be in a `try` block, with `if(handle.IsAllocated) handle.Free();` in a `finally` block

Comment: @Charlieface I get an exeption that reads "MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed." when using ms.GetBuffer.

Comment: @Jimi I can convert the memorystream to byte[] and back but for some reason the software crashes when it tries to access the data located at handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().

Comment: @nbk I will try using UnmanagedMemoryStream and see if accessing the data at the pointer will also crash the application.

Comment: So basically all of your approaches seem to work. Does anybody want to write an answer? I think I will need to ask a similar question for another object type but I don't want to mix questions here. So consider this question solved. thanks a lot to all of you!

Comment: Those are just suggestions / questions that investigate possibilities. Hence something that may make you consider the problem from a different angle. Not really *amswers*, but a form of *feedback* that may help to solve the problem. If you actually came out with working code, then post that code yourself, as an answer. Then accept it, when possible. -- Use `MemoryStream.ToArray()` if you need to *extract* the data, not `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()`: the latter includes the pre-emptive buffer allocation that doesn't necessarily contain your data.

Comment: @Jimi added my code. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I used based on the input in the comments:

---

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = MyMemoryStream.ToArray()
Dim gcHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim myPointer As IntPtr = gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
```

---

Basically you have to convert the memorystream to a byte array. You can then pin this array and get a pointer to it.

Thanks again to all the commenters!